# When/Why does Oracle adds NaN to a row in a database table

Tags: sql, oracle, nan

I know that NaN stands for Not a Number. But, I have trouble understanding when and why Oracle adds this to a row.

Is it when it encounters a value less than 0 like a negative number or when its a garbage value.

Comment: 0 and negative value are also valid, so they are not NaN. So Garbage value could be a reason, although you have to make an effort to insert a garbage value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[From the documentaton](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50979):

> The Oracle Database numeric data types store positive and negative fixed and floating-point numbers, zero, infinity, and values that are the undefined result of an operation—"not a number" or `NAN`.

As far as I'm aware you can only get NaN in a [binary_float or binary_double](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50982) column; those data types have [their own literals for NaN too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00220), and there's an [`is nan` condition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions003.htm#SQLRF52113) for them too, and the [`nanvl()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions103.htm) to manipulate them.

An example of a way to get such a value is to divide a zero float/double value by zero:

```
select 0f/0 from dual;

0F/0
----
NaN
```

... so if you're seeing NaNs your application logic or underlying data might be broken. (Note you can't get this with a 'normal' number type; you get `ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero` unless the numerator is float or double).

You won't get NaN for zero or negative numbers though. It's also possible you have a string column and an application is putting the word 'NaN' in, but storing numbers as strings is a bad idea on many levels, so hopefully that is not the case.

Comment: I'd be willing to be the last one... the only time I've ever run into NaN in Oracle that _wasn't_ created by a runaway application somewhere was when I was trying to be too clever and failing miserably :-).

Comment: Thanks Alex. You nailed it. I was getting a NaN because of a division by 0

Comment: But what if NaN is a normal value to show that the number cannot be calculated with given input to distinguish from missing value which is shown by nulls?

Comment: @kirhgoff - true NaN is a normal 'value' but only applies for these two data types. Displaying NaN as a string (or storing, which would be bad) based on application logic, maybe when an ORA-01476 is encountered, is completely different. So not really sure what you mean. If you are doing something else or this doesn't address your issue you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Nope <=0 is still a number so not quite. NaN (or infinity) are special values that the DB uses to keep it's sanity when dealing with non-computable numbers (+-∞, or simply something that is not a number).
Here's some code:

```
DECLARE
  l_bd_test   binary_double;
  l_int_test  INTEGER;
BEGIN
  l_bd_test   := 'NAN';
  l_int_test  := 0;
  IF l_bd_test IS NAN THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_bd_test || ' IS NAN');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_bd_test || ' IS A #');
  END IF;
  IF l_int_test IS NAN THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_int_test || ' IS NAN');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_int_test || ' IS A #');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Substitute `NAN` for `INFINITY` or even negate it and see the results.