# Write Python dataframe to Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

I have a dataframe `testdata` like this:
[image]
Here are the variables' types in Python:

```
detectorid:int64
starttime:str
volume:float64
speed:float64
occupancy:float64
```

Now I want to creat a datatable in oracle and insert this dataframe into it, here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
host = "192.168.1.100"    
port = "1521"    
sid = "orcl"  
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, sid)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("scott", "tiger", dsn)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#creat datatable：
sql_creat = "create table portland(detectorid number(32), starttime varchar(32), volume number(32), speed number(32), occupancy number(32))"
cursor.execute(sql_creat)

query = "insert into portland (detectorid,starttime,volume,speed,occupancy) VALUES (%d,'%s',%f,%f,%f)"
#insert by rows：
for i in range(len(testdata)):
        detectorid= testdata.ix[i,0]
        starttime= testdata.ix[i,1]
        volume= testdata.ix[i,2]
        speed= testdata.ix[i,3]
        occupancy= testdata.ix[i,4]
        cursor.execute(query % (detectorid,starttime,volume,speed,occupancy))

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

However it gives me `DatabaseError: ORA-00984:column not allowed here`. I think there are something wrong about the columns' types in my sql statement but I don't know how to solve it. Could somebody give me some instructions? Thank you for your attention!

Comment: The datatype `NUMBER` doesn't accept `NaN`, you might have to look into the datatype `BINARY_DOUBLE`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461229/when-why-does-oracle-adds-nan-to-a-row-in-a-database-table) for instance.

Comment: And it's better (much better) to store dates as datatype `DATE` or, if you have timezones, `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Hi @wolφi. I changed all `number(32)` into `BINARY_DOUBLE` and `VARCHAR(32)` into `DATE` but still get the same error. Is my `query =` code correct?

Comment: Sorry, don't know as I'm new to python. I tried your example without testdata but simple variables instead, and this worked perfectly.

Comment: @wolφi Could you be so kind to provide the code that you have tried? It may be helpful.

Comment: It looks nearly identical to your code. I'm in a hurry, I'll post it as an answer, which I'll delete after you've read it, ok?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import cx_Oracle
import os

conn = cx_Oracle.connect("user", "xxx", "localhost:1512/ORCLPDB1", encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = conn.cursor()

#creat datatable：
sql_creat = "create table portland(detectorid number(32), starttime varchar(32), volume number(32), speed number(32), occupancy number(32))"
#cursor.execute(sql_creat)

query = "insert into portland (detectorid,starttime,volume,speed,occupancy) VALUES (%d,'%s',%f,%f,%f)"
detectorid = 1345
starttime = '2011-09-15 00:00:00'
volume = 0
speed = 0
occupancy= 0
cursor.execute(query % (detectorid,starttime,volume,speed,occupancy))

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Since your code run perfectly, I think my problem is about the `nan`.

Comment: This code is open to security and scalability issues.  It should be converted to use bind variables instead of the %d etc format specifiers.